# PyTorch ResNet implementation's Training Loss increasing with every Epoch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, training-data, resnet

I'm implementing a ResNet network from scratch using PyTorch. This network is unique to my requirements, since **I need to perform Image Classification for Satellite Imagery with 14 different channels and of dimensions 8x8 pixels**.

However, my issue is that during training, *the Training Loss starts massively increasing right after the first epoch, and then reaches Infinity within 10 epochs*, and my accuracy is stuck at 0.17.

Here is the flow of my processing and the ResNet architecture:

1. I reshape the 8x8 dimension images into 64x64 using Bicubic Interpolation.
2. I pass this image through an initial Conv2d Layer with 256 out channels, kernel size of 3 and stride of 2, to roughly halve the image dimensions while increasing its channels.
3. Next, the previous output is passed through a Residual Bottleneck Block. This Residual Block consists of:

   a. Conv2d Layer with a 1x1 kernel of stride 1 with 128 filters

   b. Conv2d Layer with a 3x3 kernel with stride 1, padding 1 and 128 filters

   c. Conv2d Layer with a 1x1 kernel with stride 1 with 256 filters

   In between these Conv2d Layers, I have ReLU + Batch Normalization Layers. At its ending, the Residual Block has a Dropout Layer with a p-value of 0.1.
   The output of this Residual Block is added to the output of Step 2.
4. The output of Step 3 is now passed through the same Residual Bottleneck Block defined above - however, *before the summation can happen, I resize both the output of this Block and the output of Step 3 using a Conv2d layer*.

   The Conv2d layer will halve the dimensions of the image while doubling the number of channels to 512, using a 1x1 kernel of stride 2. Once both of them are resized through this conv2d block, they are summed up.
5. The output of Step 4 is passed through a new Residual Block - this one has the following dimensions:

   a. Conv2d Layer with a 1x1 kernel of stride 1 with 256 filters

   b. Conv2d Layer with a 3x3 kernel with stride 1, padding 1 and 256 filters

   c. Conv2d Layer with a 1x1 kernel with stride 1 with 512 filters

   In between these Conv2d Layers, I have ReLU + Batch Normalization Layers. At its ending, this Residual Block has a Dropout Layer with a p-value of 0.1.
   The output of this Residual Block is added to the output of Step 4.
6. Finally, I pass this through a Flattening layer and 2 Fully Connected Layers with a ReLU layer in between them. The last layer outputs the Class Probabilities.

**My training data consists of 588 training images for 7 different classes**. I know that a dataset of 588 images is very small - but I wished to confirm the exact reason for why my model isn't getting trained. Is it just the size of the dataset itself? Or is there something wrong with my architecture itself? I can post my code if needed as well.